# LiveCycle expanding table requiring total to equal 100

Tags: livecycle

LiveCycle -- novice user. I have an expanding table where people enter the percentage of time they spend on a job duty. The bottom line of the table adds up all the percentages. I want an error to pop up if the total doesn't equal 100.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include the details of what you tried and what errors you encountered.

Comment: I've tried putting an "if" statement in the total, but because that field is a calculated field it doesn't have an "event" and it's not working. I have a submit button to check work at the bottom of the form, but if I add an "if" statement to that to check the total, then it doesn't check the rest of my mandatory fields.

Comment: Formula for submit button to check total is:if(descriptionofworksubform.descriptionofworktable.FooterRow.NumericField11.rawValue!=100){
  app.alert("Section 12 '%of time' must add-up to 100%");
  }